# Task module in Tabs Bot framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm invoking a task module in Teams tabs on click of a button, but while closing the Task module it giving me below error.

[image: Error="User cancelled/closed the task module"]

I'm using bot framework v3.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Just need help troubleshooting that error? Node or C#? Please confirm you are using [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/tree/master/CSharp) edition (for v3) of the Teams extension. Also, share specifically which [version](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/releases) you are using (if using nuget or npm) or if you built it yourself from the repo.

Comment: while closing the task module i'm getting that error, want to know why its giving error and how to resolve it.

Comment: You need to call  microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(); within sumbitHandler() of task module. Please give a try and let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: How do i close my task module, as per MSWT documentation if i do   microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(); without any parameter it will close the task module but its not happenning

Comment: Could you please provide some piece of code what are you trying so we can look into it?

Comment: I'm having a task module with a input form and on click of submit button i'm making a ajax call, on success of ajax i'm calling ```  microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask();``` to close the task module, but its not getting close.

Comment: Where you are handling submitTask() it should go inside the submitHandler. Please try this code 
  public submitHandler(err, result) {microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask();}
You can pass action in your submitHandler to close different task module pop up. This will be for Tabs not for Bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually by design - it's not really an "error", but this is how the Task Module tells the calling tab that it's been closed directly by the user (e.g. by the user clicking the "x" to close or hitting the Escape key).

You can check for that scenario directly in your code - the Result being null, and the error being "User cancelled/closed the task module." to know that this is what the user has done. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-tabs#task-module-invocation-errors) in the docs where it's listed directly.